# Finder Error -10814

Tags: bash, applescript, finder, smb

The exact Error I am getting is

```
21:126: execution error: Finder got an error: An error of type -10814 has occurred. (-10814)
```

I am getting this error when I am trying to run an applescript trying to mount a shared server as follows

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to open location mount volume "smb://<username:pswd>@<ipaddress>/path/to/SharedFolder/"'
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is what I am trying to do not allowed?
Where can I find documentation about these error codes?

Answer (score 1):

`mount volume` and `open location` are part of Standard Additions and not related to the Finder at all.

The error occurs because you cannot pass the result of `mount volume` to `open location` (type mismatch).

The solution is to build the URL to the folder

```
osascript -e 'open location ("file://" & POSIX path of (mount volume "smb://<username:pswd>@<ipaddress>/path/to/SharedFolder/"))'
```

However this does not work if the path contains space characters. In this case you have to use the Finder to get the (percent escaped) URL of the folder. The requires at least a second line and I'm not that familiar with osascript. But this might work, too

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to open (mount volume "smb://<username:pswd>@<ipaddress>/path/to/SharedFolder/")'
```